# My program does not stop even if i have return statement

Tags: java, while-loop, subtraction

My code doesn't seem to work. After the part where it ask how much are you going to pay it wont continue to the addition solving part. Also it keeps on looping on asking "how much would you like to pay for this semester"

```
while (true) {
    if (semester.equalsIgnoreCase(First)) {
        System.out.print("\nThe Enrollment fee for this Semester is: " + balance);
        System.out.print("\nChoose your Payment term(Partial/Full): ");
        String term = st.nextLine();

        if (term.equalsIgnoreCase(partial)) {
            System.out.print("\nHow much would you like to pay for this semester: ");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            payment = in.nextInt();

            balance = balance - payment;

            System.out.print("\nYour Balance is: SR" + balance);
            if (balance > payment) {
                System.out.print("\nYou have remaining balance of: SR" + balance);
            } else if (balance == payment) {
                System.out.print("\nYou are already paid");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also this code goes from `if(semester.equalsIgnoreCase(First))` to `if(semester.equalsIgnoreCase(Third))` with the same codes.

Comment: Are you creating two `Scanner`s?

Answer (score 3):

You do the calculation to make balance the remaining balance

```
balance = balance - payment;
```

And then afterwards you check

```
 if(balance > payment)
```

as well as checking

```
else if(balance == payment)
```

Both of those statements should be checking if balance due is greater than 0, not comparing it to the payment remaining.
Your solution will keep looping until you enter half the balance (ex: $10 balance is due, you pay $5, remaining balance will be $5, thus balance = payment).